# swift ios get convert curl to swift curl using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, curl, header, alamofire

I have my curl below i want to execute it in swift using alamofire  as a post request, does anyone has the idea? what is something wrong with my code .

```
curl curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"      -H "Authorization: Bearer 05BE1EA85FDC05919A37ADF7E93fF518"      -X POST "https://b28831d6-7859-4e19f-a929-7ec4b73f6acb.pushnotifications.pusher.com/publish_api/v1/instances/b28d831d6-7859-4e19-a929-7ec4b73f6acb/publishes"      -d '{"interests":["hello"],"apns":{"aps":{"alert":{"title":"Hello","body":"Hello, world!"}}}}'
{"publishId":"pubid-fc883ab1-0c7f-420a-b864-7ccb1c04cc78"}
4LOOP-MAC-MINI:Fridgeboard_iOS-master-2 test.tesst$
```

a

```
lamofire code

 func sendTextToServer(text: String) {
//    
        let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer 05BE1EA85FDC05919A37ADF7E9d3F518", "Content-Type": "application/json"]

//
        let parameters: Parameters = "["interests":["hello"],"apns":["aps":["alert":"title":"Hello","body":"Helloworld!"]"


        Alamofire.request("https://b28831d6-785d9-4e19-a929-7ec4b73f6acb.pushnotifications.pusher.com/publish_api/v1/instances/b28831d6-7859-4e19-a929-7ec4b73f6dacb/publishes", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in

            if let dictionary = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                let json = JSON(dictionary)
//                if let textToSpeech = json["result"]["fulfillment"]["speech"].string {
//                    self.speakText(text: t    extToSpeech)
//                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Plz recheck typo in `"alert":"title":"Hello"`

Comment: how about the full code sir?

Comment: I think you miss something here, because of yours has 2 `:` in this

Comment: and the rest of the code as per your assessment?

Comment: `"""
        [
            "interests":["hello"],
            "apns":[
                "aps":"alert":, "title":"Hello", "body":"Helloworld!"
            ]
        ]   
        """`

Comment: is that the only that is wrong in my code request?

Comment: have you notice other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168606/discussion-between-durn-kurvirck-and-quoc-nguyen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using a Custom Per Request Header.

Create a dictionary for your custom headers:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json"]
```

HTTPHeaders is just a dictionary of strings:

```
public typealias HTTPHeaders = [String: String]
```

Then pass the headers as an argument in your call to create a request:

```
// In the empty quotes, enter you API url info.
let urlString = "" Alamofire.request(urlString, headers: headers).responseJSON { ... }
```

To make sure your headers are being sent, you can use debugPrint:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json"]

//In the empty quotes, enter you API url info.
let request = Alamofire.request("", headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in 
        // ...
    }
debugPrint(request)
```

From there, you are ready to create the POST call.